# Generate a directed graph for a list of string pairs

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization

I would like to generate a directed graph made of a list of string pairs using Python. It want to the first item to be pointing to the second item and each unique value to appear only once in the graph so that in the end a get a map of relationships between unique values:

Example input:

```
word_pairs = [['apple', 'tree'], ['peach', 'tree'], ['tree', 'orchard'], ['grass', 'orchard'], ['sun', 'orchard']]
```

Output:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF7GR.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have networkx [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/install.html) and matlibplot [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html) installed via pip install and from there I recommend that you use tuples in the list rather than square brackets

```
import networkx as netx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
word_pairs = [('apple', 'tree'), ('peach', 'tree'), ('tree', 'orchard'), ('grass', 'orchard'), ('sun', 'orchard')]
graph = netx.DiGraph()
graph.add_edges_from(word_pairs)

pos = netx.spring_layout(graph)
""" This will implement a graph based on force directed algorithm (best way to showcase a graph like this with minimal
 crossings and overall good looking) if you don't care much about the graph label positions"""

netx.draw_networkx_edges(graph,pos, edgelist=graph.edges(), edge_color="blue", node_size=6, arrowsize=5,
                         min_source_margin=12, min_target_margin=12)
netx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos, font_size=10, font_color="black")
plot.show()
```

Keep in mind that each time you generate the graph its mostly random due to the force direct method, but if you require fixed label positions I recommend to check out the networkx docs for drawing [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html?)